# Compiler is warning about nonmatching function declarations involving arrays

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to write a function that accepts an array as a parameter. However, the C compiler (lcc) is issuing a warning (i.e. my file still compiles) that ".\tetris.c:179: warning: declaration of `clear_array' does not match previous declaration at .\tetris.c:172".

Here is the portion of my code involving the function and a call to that function that's raising the warning:

```
void remove_filled_rows ()
{
    int row;
    for (row = 0; row < NROWS; row++) {
        // [snip] 
        if (col == NCOLS) {
            clear_array (cells[row]);    // line 172
        }
    }

}

/* Helper method that clears a row */
void clear_array (lc4uint row_array[]) {    // line 179
    int col;
    for (col = 0; col < NCOLS; col++) {
        row_array[col] = 0;
    }
}
```

My array is declared as follows:

```
lc4uint cells[NROWS][NCOLS];
```

where NROWS and NCOLS are integer constants, and `lc4uint` is simply a typedef to `unsigned int`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The declaration has to come before the access. Either move `clear_array` to before you call it or add a prototype for the `clear_array` function prior to the call. You should have gotten an error/warning about this on any decent compiler.

The give away -- line 172 wasn't supposed to be the declaration, line 179 was. But the error said 172 was the declaration.

Comment: @GiantMarshmallow gcc's message may be a bit more helpful, it speaks of the previous _implicit_ declaration. By using it before the declaration, you implicitly declare it (with a return type of int).

Answer (score 0):

```
lc4uint cells[NROWS][NCOLS]; // == lc4uint cells[NROWS*NCOLS]
```

a declaration like this generates a 1 dimensional array in memory (although you can access it with two indices) which you can only refer in function declarations as:

```
fun(lc4uint cells[][NCOLS]);
```

because the type of cells is

```
lc4uint *
```

so in `clear_array (cells[row])`; `cells[row]` is one element and of type `lc4uint` hence no matching types of the function declarations. Since no declaration was given up to that point the compiler assumes now:
`clear_array(lc4uint)` whereas you were interested in `clear_array(lc4uint *)`

You must change your array declaration to something like

```
lc4uint **cells = (lc4uint**) calloc(NROWS, sizeof(lc4uint*));
lc4uint *tmp = (lc4uint *) calloc(NROWS*NCOLS, sizeof(lc4uint))
for(int i = 0; i < NROWS; i++) cells[i] = &(tmp[i*NCOLS])
```

otherwise `cells[row]` does not return a pointer to the correct row.